# How to insert dynamic string into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a `JS` function that takes a `JS` array and uses the content to make an `HTML` table but when I try to use the code, the table doesn't show on my Website. This is the function that I am using and I tried calling the function using a button:

```html
<input type = "button" onclick = "makeTableHTML()" value = "Display">

<script> 
    function makeTableHTML() {
        var result = "<table class=\"table table-bordered table-striped\">";
        result += "<thead>";
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<th>RIF</th>";
        result += "<th>Nombre</th>";
        result += "</tr>";
        result += "</thead>";
        result += "<tbody id=\"myTable\">";                    
        for(var i=0; i<arreglo_rif.length; i++) {
            result += "<tr>";
            result += "<td>"+arreglo_rif[i]+"</td>";
            result += "<td>"+arreglo_nombre[i]+"</td>";                                
            result += "</tr>";
        }
        result += "</tbody>";
        result += "</table>";
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
</script>
```

but when I click on the button the table doesn't show either.

Comment: You create an HTML string, but you don't do anything with it

Comment: Change `return result;` to `document.body.appendChild(result);` so that the table will be added to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Also if you want to put quotes inside of other quotes, you can just use single quotes inside of the doubles instead of escaping the quotes with `\"`, for example: `"<tbody id='myTable'>"`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Also, thank you, Scott Marcus, for your understanding. I can see that I could have been more clear with my question but as for the research effort, I have tried several things and making my question here was kind of a last restort. Not everybody is born an expert.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arreglo_rif=['one','two','three']
var arreglo_nombre=[1,2,3]

function makeTableHTML() {
    var result = "<table class=\"table table-bordered table-striped\">";
    result += "<thead>";
    result += "<tr>";
    result += "<th>RIF</th>";
    result += "<th>Nombre</th>";
    result += "</tr>";
    result += "</thead>";
    result += "<tbody id=\"myTable\">";                    
    for(var i=0; i<arreglo_rif.length; i++) {
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<td>"+arreglo_rif[i]+"</td>";
        result += "<td>"+arreglo_nombre[i]+"</td>";                                
        result += "</tr>";
    }
    result += "</tbody>";
    result += "</table>";
    
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = result;
    
}
```

```html
<input type = "button" onclick = "makeTableHTML()" value = "Display">

<div id='container'></div>
```